# Sorting out date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting, date, datetime

For example we have dates like:

```
04/04/2017
12/12/2016
03/04/2016
```

How can you order the dates that it will result to:

```
11/12/2016
03/04/2016
12/04/2017
```

`ORDER BY ASC/DESC` doesn't work. Please help.

BTW I have datas of medicines with expiration dates on them. I just want that the 1st data on my listview will be the medicine that will be the 1st to expire.

Comment: it is not ordered: 11/12/2016 03/04/2016 12/04/2017 & what the type of your date field?

Comment: varchar. I think that's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
 STR_TO_DATE('04-04-2017', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

you'll convert your date-containing varchar into a DATE data type. Those sort correctly.

So,

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(expireation_date_column, '%d/%m/%Y') NULLS FIRST
```

will give you a useful ordering. The `NULLS FIRST` part will show you the rows with improperly formatted dates, if you have any, at the top of your ordering.

If this is a big project, you might be wise to convert these expiration dates to a DATE datatype when you insert them into the table. That way, you get all kinds of benefits including the ability to use indexes to search for these dates.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

where your date saved as varchar in this format dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Surely using the DateTime datatype, rather than Varchar is the best solution?

You'll get a more efficient query plan sorting on an indexed DateTime column compared to a date time conversion of a Varchar.

This will also prevent invalid dates being stored, which is possible with Varchar.

An indexed Datetime column will also help if you are querying on the column.

Comment: Everything's new to me. But then again I solved the problem. My problem before I converted it to varchar is that the format of the date time picker is not compatible with the mysql date type.

Comment: This should not dictate your database design - that's bad practice. You should convert the value from the date picker to the DateTime format Mysql accepts when inserting the record.